# How to consider an argument as a parameter in a function (if feasible?)

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I wonder whether it is possible - and if so, how - to use an argument as a function parameter. I would like to be able to put in the parameters of my function, the 'ord' argument of numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord = ...) 
I want my function to depend on a term which, depending on its value, changes the norm used. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to declare a function that evaluates the norm on an array, and allows you to pass in an order you can use something like this:

```py
def norm_with_ord(x, order):
    return numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord = order)
```

Though that still requires that you need to pass in one of the valid ordering values [as listed here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).